# Can I create a custom checkbox/button to show/hide a selection of faces?

Tags: interface, faces

Let's say that I've got a character model that has a set of armor on it. I'd like to be able to hide or show pieces of that armor by toggling them on and off via a checkbox or button that's associated with specific pieces, instead of just relying on show/hide via H/Alt+H. Is this possible?

Comment: you could put your armor on another Layer for example (Collections in next Blender)

Comment: yeah. just separate the objects and put them in separate layers. After everything is done you can combine them again to make a single mesh